SQL dateadd function for last month doesn't work?
I've been using this date function for quite some time to report on activities from the previous month. During manual validation, everything has always checked out as correct until today. I am using SSMS v19.0.20209.
With the code below I am expecting a return of where the CompletedAt date falls within last month (July 2024). However, the results include CompletedAt back to 5/31. I am perplexed, any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
DECLARE @lastMonthBegin AS Date
DECLARE @lastMonthEnd AS Date

SET @lastMonthBegin = CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(d,-(DAY(DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE() - 2))), DATEADD(m, -1, GETDATE() - 1)), 106)
SET @lastMonthEnd = CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(d, -(DAY(GETDATE())), GETDATE()), 106)

SELECT 
    OrderDriverAssignmentID,
    CompletedAt,
    IsActive  
FROM
    TOrderDriverAssignment   
WHERE 
    TOrderDriverAssignment.CompletedAt >= @lastMonthBegin
    AND TOrderDriverAssignment.CompletedAt <=  @lastMonthEnd

I've tried also replacing the variables of @lastmonthbegin & @lastmonthend with what they're declared as.

are you trying to get a range such as (if run today, 7/31) as 6/1 - 6/30, and if run tomorrow (8/1), getting dates of 7/1 - 7/31 ?

Can you show us reproducable sample data and expected result

to get the first day of the prior month you can try DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(dateadd(month, -1, getdate()), -1))

Thanks for the quick replies.  @GuidoG Here is the data that is being produced.  The expected result would only be lines 1-21, whereas lines 22-41 shouldn't be present:  Sorry - it isn't allowing me to paste results.

Here's the paste of results: https://ctxt.io/2/AABYGqBdFg

@SeanC It is currently 8/1 10:10am server time and I forgot to mention - all datetimes in the database are stored in CST (US) - Yes I know, bad design, but I inherited this.  What I'm expecting by running this today on 8/1 is that the CompletedAt is from 7/1 - 7/31.

@GuidoG DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(dateadd(month, -1, getdate()), -1)) worked by replacing the @lastMonthBegin!  Can you share what I should use for @lastMonthEnd?

@testing-for-ya Thanks.  As you can probably tell, I've learned SQL between the classes I took 20 years ago, not touching for a decade plus, then using google.  Do you have the declaration DATEADD metric that I should use for @thisMonthBegin?

All resolved, thank you all!

FYI the version of SSMS is irrelevant as its just a UI, you want select @@version. Also when adding supporting data, add it to your question directly, not in a link in a comment.

all datetimes in the database are stored in CST (US) What datatype does this column have ? I sure hope it's date or datetime or datetime2

it isn't allowing me to paste results Yes it is, but not as an image off course. Always share data in a format we can copy/paste, you don't expect us to setup a test by typing data over from an image do you

 Can you share what I should use for @lastMonthEnd? why not just simple eomonth(dateadd(month, -1, getdate()))

I validated this across multiple use cases:
SET @thisMonthBegin = DATEADD(DAY, 1, EOMONTH(getdate(), -1));
SET @lastMonthBegin = DATEADD(MONTH, -1, @thisMonthBegin);

WHERE TOrderDriverAssignment.CompletedAt  >= @lastMonthBegin
AND TOrderDriverAssignment.CompletedAt <  @thisMonthBegin


You should accept @testing-for-ya's answer instead of posting reposting what is essentially a duplicate answer.

As long as the verion of SQL server is 2016 or greater, you can use EOMONTH to make the calculations. This is code I use:
DECLARE @StartDate DATE = dateadd(day,1,eomonth(getdate(),-2))  -- start of previous month
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = eomonth(getdate(),-1) 

Which would make your comparison CompletedAt BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
Because I have hours, minutes, and seconds to consider, I use a slightly modified version of this:
DECLARE @EndDate DATE = dateadd(month, 1, @startDate) 

This makes the comparison CompletedAt >= @StartDate and CompletedAt <@EndDate
